# Failed to download template from registry: fetch failed when init nuxt project

Tags: node.js, npm, nuxt.js

npx nuxi@latest init b-client

ERROR  Error: Failed to download template from registry: fetch failed

[image]

I modify the host file but it didn't work.

I modify the DNS profile but it didn't work.

I use all methods I could find online,but there is no one worked.

Comment: Tried those? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A8816585+registry

Answer (score 0):

Change your DNS to 8.8.8.8 (Google DNS Or An DNS Resolver)

In `Linux`

```
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

```
# nameserver 192.168.1.1 X change it to this
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

[image]

[image: ERROR Error: Failed to download template from registry: fetch failed]